# Perlin Noise Assistance

Tags: 2d, interpolation, smoothing, noise, perlin-noise

Ok so I found [this](http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/models/m_perlin.htmm) article and I am confused by some parts of it.  If anyone can explain this process in more depth to me I would greatly appreciate it because I have been trying to code this for 2 months now and still have not gotten a correct version working yet.  I am specifically confused about the Persistence part of the article because I mostly do not understand what the author is trying to explain about it and at the bottom of the article he talks about a 2D pseudo code implementation of this but the PerlinNoise_2D function does not make sense to me because after the random value is smoothed and interpolated, it is an integer value but the function takes float values?  Underneath the persistence portion there is the octaves part.  I do not quite understand because he "adds" the smoothed functions together to get the Perlin function.  What does he mean by"adds" because you obviously do not add the values together.  So if anyone can explain these parts to me I would be very happy.  Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TerrainGen extends JPanel {

public static int layers = 3;
public static float[][][][] noise = new float[16][16][81][layers];
public static int[][][][] octaves = new int[16][16][81][layers];
public static int[][][][] perlin = new int[16][16][81][layers];
public static int[][][] perlinnoise = new int[16][16][81];
public static int SmoothAmount = 3;
public static int interpolate1 = 0;
public static int interpolate2 = 10;
public static double persistence = 0.25;

//generate noise
//smooth noise
//interpolate noise
//perlin equation

public TerrainGen() {
    for(int t = 0; t < layers; t++) {
        for(int z = 0; z < 81; z++) {
            for(int y = 0; y < 16; y++) {
                for(int x = 0; x < 16; x++) {
                    noise[x][y][z][t] = GenerateNoise();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for(int t = 0; t < layers; t++) {
        SmoothNoise(t);
    }

    for(int t = 0; t < layers; t++) {
        for(int z = 0; z < 81; z++) {
            for(int y = 0; y < 16; y++) {
                for(int x = 0; x < 16; x++) {
                    octaves[x][y][z][t] = InterpolateNoise(interpolate1, interpolate2, noise[x][y][z][t]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for(int t = 0; t < layers; t++) {
        PerlinNoise(t);
    }
}

public static Random generation = new Random(5);
public float GenerateNoise() {
    float i = generation.nextFloat();
    return i;
}

public void SmoothNoise(int t) {
    //Huge smoothing algorithm
}

//Cosine interpolation
public int InterpolateNoise(int base, int top, float input) {
    return (int) ((1 - ((1 - Math.cos(input * 3.1415927)) * 0.5)) + top * ((1 - Math.cos(input * 3.1415927)) * 0.5));
}

public void PerlinNoise(int t) {
    double f = Math.pow(2.0, new Double(t));
    double a = Math.pow(persistence, new Double(t));
    for(int z = 0; z < 81; z++) {
        for(int y = 0; y < 16; y++) {
            for(int x = 0; x < 16; x++) {
                perlin[x][y][z][t] = (int) ((octaves[x][y][z][t] * f) * a);
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String [] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(180, 180);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    TerrainGen test = new TerrainGen();
    frame.add(test);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static int size = 5;
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    int i = 0;
    for(int t = 0; t < 9; t++) {
        for(int z = 0; z < 9; z++) {
            for(int y = 0; y < 16; y++) {
                for(int x = 0; x < 16; x++) {
                    g.setColor(new Color(perlin[x][y][i][0] * 10, perlin[x][y][i][0] * 10, perlin[x][y][i][0] * 10));
                    g.fillRect((z * (16 * size)) + (x * size), (t * (16 * size)) + (y * size), size, size);
                }
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
    repaint();
}
}
```

And I did not include the smoothing part because that was about 400 lines of code to smooth between chunks.

Comment: Are you really a doctor *and* a professor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the article calls persistence is how the amplitude of the higher frequency noises "falls off" when they are combined.

"octaves" are just what the article calls the noise functions at different frequencies.

You take 1.0 and repeatedly multiply by the persistence to get the list of amplitudes to multiply each octave by - e.g. a persistence of 0.8 gives factors 1.0, 0.8, 0.64, 0.512.

The noise is not an integer, his function Noise1 produces noise in the range 0..1 - i.e. variable n is an Int32 bit it returns a float.

The input paramters are integers i.e. The Noise1 function is only *evaluated* at (1, 0) or (2, 2). 
After smoothing/smearing the noise a bit in SmoothNoise_1 the values get interpolated to produce the values inbetween.

Hope that helped!!

Comment: And the frequency is just multiplied by 2 every time?

Comment: Yes, but i't probably wouldn't matter if you used other factors for upping the frequency.

Comment: Ok thanks and 1 or 2 more questions... What order does this process go in? Generate noise, smooth, interpolate, then use the perlin equation or something else?

Comment: Then I am doing that part right but the code still does not generate anything close to what the noise is supposed to look like... I think it is the perlin noise equation itself.  Hahaha can you explain one last thing, the perlin noise equation written in pseudo code in the article.  I do not understand what values for x and y it takes and why it needs them because the line "total = total + InterpolatedNoisei(x * frequency, y * frequency) * amplitude" is seriously confusing me

Comment: Try 0..1 for the ranges - what part of it is confusing you?

Comment: When I interpolate the data, should it be returning float values instead of integer values? And the last part of the equation:

total = total + InterpolatedNoisei(x * frequency, y * frequency) * amplitude

is confusing me because I thought I already interpolated the noise and what function is it calling with the x * frequency and y * frequency as the inputs for the function?  Also, why does it add the last total to the new total?

Comment: Yes the interpolation should return floats. You call the interpolation inside the loop, so you're calling it once per "octave". The total should start at 0 then you are adding each octave to it.

Comment: Wait what? Isn't the octave the array of data (noise)?  And the interpolation, what is the point if the input is already a float?

Comment: The pseudocode doesn't process arrays, can you post your code?

Comment: I posted my code.  The arrays are 81 2D arrays making up 1 huge 2D array for chunking and each 4th dimensional value is another randomly generated noise array

Comment: Ok unfortunately I don't know much java. Looks like you are trying to use cosine instead of linear interpolation, but I don't see how you pass the interpolands to that function, also looks like you are processing it all in 3-4d arrays which shouldn't be necessary for the 2d case. Maybe start simple and implement it as per the pseudocode?

Comment: Ok well just take this equation:  total = total + InterpolatedNoisei(x * frequency, y * frequency) * amplitude  : and tell me what InterpolatedNoisei is and why it takes x * frequency and y * frequency as parameters

Comment: InterpolatedNoise linearly interpolates the smoothed noise values inside the square formed by points (x, y), (x+1, y), (x+1, y+1), (x, y+1). The multiplication by frequency is what makes the higher octaves have more fine variations than the low ones.

Comment: But that would not make sense because if you ran that interpolation method you would get errors because it would try and access a -1 slot in the array which does not exist.  So is there any way I could just take some values from the arrays I have already smoothed and use those?

Comment: And also the smoothing function does this: 

function SmoothNoise_1(float x, float y)
    corners = ( Noise(x-1, y-1)+Noise(x+1, y-1)+Noise(x-1, y+1)+Noise(x+1, y+1) ) / 16
    sides   = ( Noise(x-1, y)  +Noise(x+1, y)  +Noise(x, y-1)  +Noise(x, y+1) ) /  8
    center  =  Noise(x, y) / 4
    return corners + sides + center
  end function

But you cannot subtract or add 1 to a float

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8464/discussion-between-mrdrprofessortyler-and-peter-wishart)

Comment: Here is an example of an octaves loop... it adds multiple noises together... ok i can't comment with code. ill provide an answer.     function lnzo ( vtx: Vector3 ): float
{
 var total = 0.0; 
 for (var i:int = 1; i < 7; i ++)
 {
  total+= lnz2(Vector3 (vtx.x*(i*i),0.0,vtx.z*(i*i)))/(i*i);
 }

 return total;

}

Answer (score 0):

this loop makes octaves from 2d noise. same loop would work for 3d perlin...

```
   function octaves( vtx: Vector3 ): float
    {
        var total = 0.0;    
        for (var i:int = 1; i < 7; i ++)//num octaves
        {
            total+= PerlinNoise(Vector3 (vtx.x*(i*i),0.0,vtx.z*(i*i)))/(i*i);
        }

        return total;//added multiple perlins into noise with 1/2/4/8 etc ratios

    }
```

the best thing i have seen for learning perlin is the following code. instead of hash tables, it uses sin based semi random function. using 2-3 octaves it becomes high quality perlin... the amazing thing is that i ran 30 octave of this on a realtime landscape and it didnt slow down, whereas i used 1 voronoi once and it was slowing. so... amazing code to learn from.

```
#ifndef __noise_hlsl_
#define __noise_hlsl_

// hash based 3d value noise
// function taken from https://www.shadertoy.com/view/XslGRr
// Created by inigo quilez - iq/2013
// License Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial-ShareAlike 3.0 Unported License.

// ported from GLSL to HLSL

float hash( float n )
{
    return frac(sin(n)*43758.5453);
}

float noise( float3 x )
{
    // The noise function returns a value in the range -1.0f -> 1.0f

    float3 p = floor(x);
    float3 f = frac(x);

    f       = f*f*(3.0-2.0*f);
    float n = p.x + p.y*57.0 + 113.0*p.z;

    return lerp(lerp(lerp( hash(n+0.0), hash(n+1.0),f.x),
                   lerp( hash(n+57.0), hash(n+58.0),f.x),f.y),
               lerp(lerp( hash(n+113.0), hash(n+114.0),f.x),
                   lerp( hash(n+170.0), hash(n+171.0),f.x),f.y),f.z);
}
```

note that sin is expensive on CPU, instead you would use:

```
function hash ( n: float ): float
{//random -1, 1
    var e = ( n *73.9543)%1;
    return  (e*e*142.05432)%2-1;// fast cpu random by me :) uses e*e rather than sin
}
```